# How can install and load mods related to videodev and others?

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, video, usb-device, camera

Same hardware,two debian-11.7 installed in the same pc ,one is on /dev/sda1,other is on /dev/ada2.

For the debian on /dev/sda1:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.178-3 (2023-04-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
sudo dmesg | grep uvc
[   16.378883] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo FHD Webcam Audio (17ef:4831)
[   16.397414] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
ls  /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1
lsmod | grep video
uvcvideo              118784  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         36864  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       65536  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              294912  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     61440  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
usbcore               331776  6 xhci_hcd,snd_usb_audio,usbhid,snd_usbmidi_lib,uvcvideo,xhci_pci
usb_common             16384  3 xhci_hcd,usbcore,uvcvideo
video                  61440  0
```

I can use the usb camera with cheese or other video soft.

For the debian on /dev/sda2:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-2 (2023-07-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
sudo dmesg | grep uvc
#nothing in the output
ls  /dev/video*
#nothing in the output
lsmod | grep video
video                  61440  0
```

Can't use usb camera with cheese,how can install and load lost mod in  /dev/sda2's debian?

Comment: strange, these seem to  be nearly the same kernels, so the automatically loaded modules should also be the same. On the one that doesn't work, when you look at `dmesg -Hwx` and plug in the camera, you will see some messages appear. Can you add these to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the blacklist line in blacklist.conf in /dev/sda2.

```
#previous
cat  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist uvcvideo
```

Delete the line :blacklist uvcvideo.